# How can I make a screenshot in the BGE (numpy of pixel values) without saving to disk?

Tags: python, game-engine, camera

I'm doing a computer vision simulation in blender game engine, so I need to make screenshots that will give me an array/numpy of pixels to do image processing on at each frame. Saving it as PNG through `bge.render.makeScreenshot(path)` and then reading values through there won't work since that will be very slow for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might try something like this:

```
import bge

source = texture.ImageRender(world,sensorView_Cam) 

source.capsize = [640,480]

imageArray = texture.imageToArray(source, 'RGB') 

charArray = imageArray.to_list()
```

works ok for me (Although, i dont know if it is fast enough for you and if there are faster ways)

Comment: It did give me some numbers but it has several problems. It's one dimensional so how do I check whether it displays what it should. It also doesn't work when sensorView_Cam is set to active, it says "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_list''". What can be done about it? Should I try to recombine the 1D vector into R G and B matrices? Because 2Dness of it is essential for some image processing algorithms like convolution (conv neural nets)

Comment: For your first question: Yes, you need to use the camera image of a non-active camera (can't tell you why, but i remember that i stumbled across the same problem).
For your second question: Yes, you need to rearange the data according to the setup of your image (R,G,B in your case).

Comment: Well than Ok. Non of them seem as a problem because I always can add another camera on top of it, parent to it and make that one active. Thank you very much.

Comment: on your example, texture refers to bge.texture, but what do (world,sensorView_Cam) refer to? The value of these variables is not defined.